# How to copy code from Jenkins server to it's docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server, I plan to use it for CI for cross platform c++ project. To simplify the process, I have two docker images, one is building the project for android NDK, and the other is building for Ubuntu. For example, I am using a Jenkins file as shown below for android build:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'image4android:latest'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'cd /path/to/project && cmake --build .' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run linting and formatting on the Jenkins master, as that is the same for all platforms. Then I need to copy the linted/formatted code to each container for building. How can I use things like `docker cp` on the Jenkins master to copy the project code to the android/ubuntu container?

Comment: I think Jenkins does some mounting by itself. If I remember correctly it will mount your workspace inside the container (could be wrong though). If it doesn't work that way you can try the Jenkins stash/unstash.

Answer (score 0):

You can set volumes in Jenkins -> Manage jenkins -> Manage Nodes and Clouds -> Configure Clouds -> Docker Agent templates -> (Add new template or use existing) -> Container settings -> Volumes

Also you can use jenkins global variables - WORKSPACE. Not shure if jenkins will use variables in the container settings.